# CodeIgniter: 4.0.3 FPDF - error Class 'FPDF' not found

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I am trying to generate a PDF document from CodeIgniter: 4.0.3 using fpdf library. I have copied fpdf library in app/ThirdParty folder.

I have included library reference at the top of controller like this.

```
    <?php namespace App\Controllers\Purchase;

     namespace App\ThirdParty\fpdf;

     use CodeIgniter\Controller;

     use FPDF;
```

I have created a class in the controller to extend FPDF to include header and footers like this.

```
    class PDF extends FPDF
    {

    
       function Header()
       {
       }
    
    }
```

I generate the pdf like this.

```
       $pdf = new PDF();
       $pdf->AddPage();
```

When I run the application, I get this error.

> Error
> Class 'FPDF' not found
> 114     class PDF extends FPDF

How to fix this?

Comment: namespace App\ThirdParty\fpdf; ? You are referring to thirdParty folder , so why are you declaring that namespace again ? To import the class you use "use App\...\tpf" like this.

Comment: Removed namespace and tried use App\ThirdParty\fpdf\fpdf; Getting Error
Class 'App\ThirdParty\fpdf\fpdf' not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should checkout whatever your namespace in fpdf lib is. It looks like you're a bit confused about them and the `use` word

Here's an example on how to load a lib which is under the `app/ThirdParty` folder :

Your FPDF main class named `FPDF.php` :

```
<?php

// the path you need to follow to access your file
namespace App\ThirdParty;

class FPDF {
    
    public function __construct() {
        // do your things
    }
}
```

Your Controller named `Foo.php` :

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

// the namespace of the lib file + its class name
use App\ThirdParty\FPDF;

class Foo extends \CodeIgniter\Controller {
    
    public function myPDF() {
        $pdf = new FPDF();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First include `font` folder, `fpdf.php` file and `fpdf.css` file in the ThirdParty folder.

Open fpdf.php file and include following 2 lines after `<?php`

```
namespace App\ThirdParty;

use Exception;
```

**Then rename the `fpdf.php` file in ThirdParty folder to `FPDF.php`**

Now you can import fpdf using:

```
use App\ThirdParty\FPDF;
```