# integrate FPDF in codeIgniter 4: library and controllers

Tags: fpdf, codeigniter-4

I want use fpdf in my project CI4..
how i can do this step by step?
How include it as thirdparty?!

```
<?php namespace App\Controllers\Purchase;

     namespace App\ThirdParty\fpdf;

     use CodeIgniter\Controller;

     use FPDF;
?>
```

and how build the controller to call fpdf methods?!

```
$pdf = new PDF();
   $pdf->AddPage();
```

thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CodeIgniter: 4.0.3 FPDF - error Class 'FPDF' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63030681/codeigniter-4-0-3-fpdf-error-class-fpdf-not-found)

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution to this today.
Assuming your fpdf.php file is in the directory app\ThirdParty

1- make the first line of the file fpdf.php look like this

```
<?php namespace App\ThirdParty;
```

2- In your controller add the line

```
use App\ThirdParty\FPDF;
```

3- Now you can create your pdf file

```
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(1,13);
$pdf->AddPage('P','A4');
$this->response->setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
$pdf->Output('test.pdf','F');
```

The file will be stored in the public directory of ci4.

I hope I've helped you.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this by using the old way (i.e adding fpdf directly in app/Controllers/);
Firstly, make sure you have the latest version of fpdf installed. Mine is 1.82 then unzip in app/Controllers.

```
require('fpdf.php');//to be done in your controller

$pdf = new \FPDF();
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(1,13);
$pdf->AddPage('P','A4');
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
$this->response->setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
$pdf->Output('test.pdf','F');
```

In case you are using XAMPP for linux kindly update fpdf in /opt/lampp/lib/php.

Answer (score 0):

First include `font` folder, `fpdf.php` file and `fpdf.css` file in the ThirdParty folder.

Open fpdf.php file and include following 2 lines after `<?php`

```
namespace App\ThirdParty;

use Exception;
```

**Then rename the `fpdf.php` file in ThirdParty folder to `FPDF.php`**

Now you can import fpdf using:

```
use App\ThirdParty\FPDF;
```